# missing data in hmmlearn from scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, hmmlearn

i'm running a simple HMM using scikit-learn's `hmmlearn` module. it works for fully observed data, but it fails when i pass it observations with missing data. small example:

```
import numpy as np
import hmmlearn
import hmmlearn.hmm as hmm

transmat = np.array([[0.9, 0.1],
                     [0.1, 0.9]])
emitmat = np.array([[0.5, 0.5],
                    [0.9, 0.1]])

# this does not work: cannot have missing data
obs = np.array([0, 1] * 5 + [np.nan] * 5)

# this works
#obs = np.array([0, 1] * 5 + [1] * 5)

startprob = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
h = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=2,
                       startprob=startprob,
                       transmat=transmat)
h.emissionprob_ = emitmat
print obs, type(obs)
posteriors = h.predict_proba(obs)
print posteriors
```

if `obs` is fully observed (every element is 0 or 1) it works but i would like to get estimates for unobserved data points. i tried encoding these as `np.nan` or `None` but neither works. it gives the error `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type` (in `hmm.py", line 430, in _compute_log_likelihood`).

how can this be done in hmmlearn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no way of doing missing data imputation using `hmmlearn`.

As an ad hoc approach you can partition the observation sequence into fully observed subsequences and then for each subsequence either pick the most likely *next* state and observation or just simulate them randomly from the transition and emission probabilities. Note that this strategy can lead to inconsistencies on the subsequence boundaries.

Comment: adding inference of next most likely sequence would be really helpful are there plans to add it?

Comment: At the moment we're focused on filling the missing parts for the 0.2.0 release. Feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn).